# Use link-to in subexpression

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

I use the [`ember-i18n`](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) library a lot and sometimes I want to output a link in a translation.

Given this example:

```
{{ t readmore link=(link-to 'top posts' 'posts') }}
```

my translation is `Read more on the {{ link }} page.`

But the output is not as I expected, the generated link is not in the translation-span but before it:

```
<a id="ember1128" class="ember-view" href="/posts">top posts</a>
<span id="i18n-8">Read more on the  page.</span>
```

I would expect it to be like this:

```
<span id="i18n-8">Read more on the <a id="ember1128" class="ember-view" href="/posts">top posts</a> page.</span>
```

Is there a way I can work arround this?

Comment: https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/issues/79#issuecomment-26533948

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link interpolation i18n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265294/link-interpolation-i18n)