# Link interpolation i18n

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I use ember-i18n to handle multiples langages in my project, and I need to insert a link inside a translation (with interpolation).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Response](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/issues/79#issuecomment-204499954) from @jamesarosen on Github :

> You can't use the `{{link-to}}` helper inside a translation because it
>   emits a DOM node, not a String.

But you can use [ember-href-to](https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to) addon to generate URLs.

In JavaScript:

```
// some-thing/component.js:
import { hrefTo } from 'ember-href-to/helpers/href-to';

text: Ember.computed('i18n.locale', function() {
  const i18n = this.get('i18n');
  const href = hrefTo(this, 'some.route');
  const link = Ember.String.htmlSafe(`<a href="${href}">Link Text</a>`);
  return i18n.t('some.translation', { link });
})
```

Or in Handlebars (you'll need an htmlSafe helper):

```
{{t 'some.translation'
  link=(htmlSafe (join '<a href="' (href-to 'some.route') '">Link Text</a>'))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar problem recently and this is what I did:

Translation file (en.json) :

```
"some.message.key": "Successfully created <a href='{{userlink}}'> {{username}} </a>."
```

In the respective template/hbs file:

```
{{html-safe (t "some.message.key" userlink=link username=name)}}
```

html-safe is a helper provided by [ember-cli-string-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-string-helpers) add on.